# How safe is opening any website on new browser tab?

Tags: encryption, passwords, web-browser, account-security, data-leakage

When I do online shopping where I use my credit card information to purchase, I clear the browser cache, cookies and only open that single site. After I am done, I again clear the cache, cookies and start with my regular browsing. I do this to ensure any other websites that I open on a new tab do not sneak into my credit card information. Is this even possible or just a myth?

So if I wish to open "any" site on a new tab while doing my online shopping, is it safe or do I have to clear cookies every time and open only one site?

Comment: credit card info isn't stored in cookies

Comment: Clearing the cache is useless for your purpose. Closing other tabs in theory can help prevent potential CSRF attempts, but in almost all cases it is extremely unlikely to be useful at all. It is much more likely that the threat comes from the online store itself (for example an infected e-commerce)

Comment: Are the websites you're giving your CC information to HTTPS?

Comment: If it was this easy, then websites wouldn't let you type in your credit card information because they'd be sued by the credit card companies for doing that.

Comment: @schroeder I want to support that your statement is absolute, I really do. However, based on code I've seen during my web development profession I wouldn't put it past a flaky developer to put CC info in a cookie.

Comment: This practice may help you avoid being taken advantage of by "Dynamic Pricing"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus at least in theory and PCI DSS, no merchant bank will allow sites built by flaky web developers to touch CC numbers until after an external security audit and penetration test that would be expected to reveal putting CC info in a cookie. And since that is expensive, almost all sites and webshops do not touch CC info in any way and just forward the user to some merchant gateway service which does handle it properly.

Comment: both firefox and chrome are trusted browsers ... you could pick one as daily driver then use other only for your banking or shopping

Comment: Also, don't worry about your _Credit Card_ being stolen. It's not your money, and you will get all of it credited back to your available credit balance. If you actually meant your debit or bank card... then stop doing that - that _is_ your money and it may or may not be replaced by your bank. Use a credit card for online shopping (and in general) and don't worry about these things.

Comment: @SnakeDoc that's mostly US-specific.

Comment: @DanM. Is it though? A credit card is a specific thing.

Comment: @SnakeDoc in a lot of places there is no difference between credit or debit cards. There, "debit" cards are just credit cards with 0 limit (usually). Also, the laws regarding "you will get all of it credited back to your available credit balance" are different and may or mat not make distinction on the type of the bank card used.

Answer (score 23):

> So if I wish to open "any" site on a new tab while doing my online shopping, is it safe

The same origin policy *should* prevent other sites from accessing your data in the online shopping site. That is assuming that the shopping site has no vulnerabilities that leak data (CSRF, XSS, XSSI, broken CORS, broken messaging, etc.).

Having only one tab open *may* mitigate some of the damage malicious sites could do. But with technology like serviceworkers, malicious sites may also be able to perform attacks even after you closed the tab. If you want additional security, you should use other mechanisms which are designed to separate different areas (e.g. private/incognito tabs/windows, different browsers, Chrome's browser profiles, or Firefox's multi-account containers).

Comment: Any link for the attack that works even after the tab is closed?

Answer (score 8):

The only useful thing about your routine is cleaning the cookies. It's not useful in itself, it is just that, this way, you delete your login session and so a new login (which requires inputting a secret like a password) is required to interact with the shopping site. A better alternative (in terms of your user experience and security) would be *logging out* from the site.

It goes untold that the CCs information is not stored in your computer but in the servers managed by the shopping site company. So that cannot be stolen from your browser and without a valid login session, no sane shopping site would allow sensible operations. If the shopping site is vulnerable, you've already lost.
If you saved your CCs in the browser (is this possible? I hope it's not just form auto-filling) they cannot be stolen from third parties (see below).

Note also that any attack that can be performed on a login session from another tab, can also be performed later when the victim site's tab had already been closed. Granted that the login session persists, client-side, after the closing (which is not the case if you log out or clear the cookies when done or wait enough time).

This is because browsing happens at discrete times and the sites cannot actually tell if the user is still viewing their page. From the shopping site's POV, unless you perform an action, you have already closed its tab, even if you are still reading an item's description. So a malicious request doesn't have to be performed while the shopping site is open, it can be performed any time later (as long as your browser can still identify itself to the site).

Web pages can't access each information other unless coming from the same origin (e.g. same domain) or explicit permission has been granted. Bug in the browser's behavior is possible but should be rare when it comes to enforcing policies.  Keep your browser updated.

Browsers can have serious vulnerabilities labeled "zero-days", that would allow a website to take over your browser. Depending on the specific attack, complete access to saved login sessions and password is entirely possible. Escalations that took over the entire machine have been demonstrated and used many times. It suffices to visit a website and it would be totally invisible. The good news is that this zero-click zero-days are worth "a lot" (though in the Apple context, they are losing their value due to the great number of them) and are generally used only against very sensitive targets (think of politicians, national security issues, industry espionage). Committing a felony is not a reason good enough to waste a zero-day on someone, let alone stealing your CC.

Depending on how paranoid you are, you can:

1. Visit the shopping site normally. You trust your browser to not be vulnerable to basic policy bypass (a rare event) and to zero-days (a quite probable event but not worth on you *at all*); You trust the site to not be vulnerable to certain attacks.
2. Visit the shopping site and log out when done.  You only trust your browser to not be vulnerable to zero-days. Even if the site is vulnerable or the browser policies are broken, without a login session the attacker could not target "you". Still, if you save your passwords they could be stolen by a zero-day (very very rare event).
3. Visit the shopping site with a different browser and log out when done. You trust *another* (possibly hardened at the cost of UX) browser to not have zero-days vulnerabilities or not to have, in your whole software park, zero-days big enough to allow a rogue browser to take over the other applications. If you use a different browser, the attacker would need to escape any sandbox the OS put around the browser (if any).
4. Avoid suspicious sites. You avoid the problem in the first place. It's impossible to avoid them all, especially because most popups auto opens. But serious attacks are targeted towards you. The usual popups on streaming sites just try to fool you, so don't worry about them, but if you find a sticker on your (and only your) door which read "visit whatever.com for free stuff!" it's best not to do so.
5. Visit the shop in person. You only trust your person to not be vulnerable to the here-is-a-knife-gimme-yer-wallet attack.

I personally go with point 2 and *never save the passwords of sensitive sites in the browser* (use a password manager if needed).

Answer (score 2):

> I do this to ensure any other websites that I open on new tab does not
> sneak into my credit card information. Is this even possible or just a
> myth?

That is simply not possible, because the browser doesn't allow such a request due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) without the website explicitly stating it in their [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers; apart from that, credit card info isn't stored in the cookies but instead stored similar to passwords, that is if you use the inbuilt browser function to store the credit card details.

> So if I wish to open "any" site on a new tab while doing my online
> shopping, is it safe or every time I have to clear cookies cache and
> open only 1 site?

No, you don't have to clear cache/cookies each time you open a new tab, that is assuming your banking website isn't vulnerable to CORS misconfiguration; even then your credit card info should be safe, but the website on the new tab would be able to perform an HTTP request to your bank if such a vulnerability is present. Hence use 2FA.